# Bind 'œ' key to '`'

Tags: key-bindings

How would you bind the useless œ (or 2-square) key from azerty keywords to enter ` (backtick, backquote, or however you want to call the symbol needed for code blocks in markdown) ?

My problems are :

- I am not sure know how to express this key as a (kbd ...) form
- I don't know how to express "insert this char".

This does *NOT* work :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "œ") (lambda () (insert "`")))
(global-set-key (kbd "œ") '(lambda () (insert "`")))
(global-set-key (kbd "œ") '(insert "`")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out which key Emacs thinks œ is by hitting `C-h k œ`.

When you want a key simply to enter a string, you can just tell
it to do so without invoking a function.  Hence, this binding
should work, assuming the "œ" part is correct:

```
(global-set-key "œ" "`")
```

You may have to replace the "œ" part with whatever Emacs thinks that key is.

Comment: Ok. My problem was that for some reason, smart-parens would not let me type the last part of this.